# Cannot reinstall Windows on Toughbook CF-19, OEM or upgrade issue?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, tablet, reinstall, oem

My Toughbook (CF-19) has a 'Windows Vista Business OEMAct, Panasonic' COA on the bottom of the unit. When I extracted the key before reformatting - it was a 'Windows XP Professional' Product Name and the Product ID code has 'OEM' in it...and I can confirm this upgrade was last OS installed (w/ Service Pack 3) - but there was the tablet functionality.

This extracted product key isn't working with any version of Windows I try installing. XP Pro, XP Pro Tablet 2005 OEM, Tablet XP OEM. Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it was licensed for Windows Vista but you/Panasonic used "Downgrade rights" to use XP Tablet Edition / Professional with tablet like programs.

The edition of Windows was not a straight forward OEM off the shelf copy but limited to disks from Panasonic. I would check to see if they gave you any media or recovery disks and if not, try and get a duplicate one from them.

Answer (score 1):

> To Our Valued Customers,
>
> Some questions have arisen as to the Panasonic policy on providing
>   “Microsoft Windows Vista including a downgrade right to Windows XP
>   Professional” (Vista downgrade). This will explain our implementation
>   of Microsoft’s program, announced in Sept. 2007 and first implemented
>   by PCSC in November, 2007. This program will be in effect until, at
>   least, April 21, 2010.
>
> - Panasonic Toughbook laptops no longer come with a Windows XP license. All systems are shipped with a Windows Vista license (and
>     Certificate of Authenticity, or COA). However, Windows XP can be
>     installed on the system prior to being shipped to the customer through
>     the “Vista downgrade” program.
> - Panasonic Toughbook laptops that ship with a “Vista downgrade” will have a Windows XP factory image loaded on the unit’s hard disk drive.
>     They will ship with a Windows Vista Certificate of Authenticity (COA),
>     as well as Windows XP recovery CD and a Windows Vista Recovery CD.
>     This will allow a user to restore the XP image or upgrade to a Windows
>     Vista Business standard factory load.
> - The user license will be for Windows Vista Business (as shown on the COA) but the user is granted downgrade rights to use Windows XP
>     Professional. There will be NO Windows XP license key with these
>     models. Panasonic may not provide an XP license key. Users must use
>     their existing corporate license or contact Microsoft to obtain one,
>     if needed.
> - Customers must use the Panasonic Windows XP recovery CD to install the Windows XP operating system. If the recovery CD is not used, the
>     customer may be prompted to provide a Windows XP license key.
>     Panasonic may not provide a Windows XP license key. Microsoft must be
>     contacted to obtain a Windows XP license key.
> - The Windows logo sticker on the wrist rest of the Toughbook laptop will show Windows Vista as the OS on the unit, but the OS that boots
>     up on the machine will be Windows XP. Units with the Vista downgrade
>     can be identified with a part number that ends in the letters “AM”.
>     (Units loaded with Windows Vista, and without a downgrade, end in
>     “JM”.)
> - All current Panasonic Toughbook laptops are available with either of the Windows operating systems. The Vista downgrade program is being
>     offered by Panasonic in cooperation with Microsoft to meet the needs
>     of users who are not yet ready to transition to Windows Vista and
>     desire a Windows XP solution for the current acquisitions. Panasonic
>     Computer Solutions Company August, 2009